# How to properly configure authentication views? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

There are two views index and index1 and my login view is

```
def loginview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        return redirect('index2')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('',loginview,name="login"),
       path('index/',index,name="index"),
       path('index2/',index2,name="index2"),
       ]
```

The code works but I want to only access index and index2 after the user is logged on or logged out.

When I navigate to localhost:8000/index and localhost:8000/index2, the page directs to the respective pages.

How to restrict authorization on these pages?

Comment: Checkout Django's docs on login: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator, you can add a decorator

Answer (score -2):

You can add a flag on your django base user class definition to create a state to control this problem

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    # other User definitions
    index_page = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
```

then when you call **loginview** you can determine the index page for user for further requests.